# how to add another name before project name in spring mvc URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My project name is MyProject so my url becomes:
http://localhost:8080/MyProject

Is there any solution where i can add another name before MyProject
eg.: http://localhost:8080/ABC/MyProject

Note: my war file name should be MyProject

Please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this case we just need to add jboss-web.xml file in WEB-INF.
jboss-web.xml:
`<context-root>/ABC</context-root>`
and in web.xml add URL-pattern in servlet-mapping
`<url-pattern>/MyProject/AA/*</url-pattern>`

and this worked!!!!